# Javascript function calling within setTimeout - which is better?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have two versions of the code. Can someone let me know which is optimal and faster?

Version 1:

```
function showMsg(a)
{
    alert(a);
}
function invokeShowMsg()
{
    var msg = 'hi';
    showMsg(msg);
}
window.setTimeout(invokeShowMsg,1000);
```

Version 2:

```
function showMsg(a)
{
    alert(a);
}
window.setTimeout(function(){showMsg('hi');},1000);
```

One more doubt, is the Version 2 way of calling called "Closure"?

Comment: What are your criteria for "optimal"? I suspect #1 is faster because it passes a reference to an already declared function rather than evaluating a function expression and passing a reference to that—but you should test it in various browsers. In any case, if execution is delayed by a minimum of 1 second, of what relevance is speed?

Comment: Since I run it in a Mobile browser, will version 2 cause any adverse impact?

Comment: You will not notice it, even if you tried. Most* JS engines compile the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as speed goes, you will not notice any difference between the two whatsoever, so pick what you like.

I prefer **#2**, as it is cleaner and keeps the syntax readable:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  showMsg('hi');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: [Is it really a closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)?

Comment: I just say yes because it makes no difference whatsoever to me, as I haven't really found a practical use for distinguishing an anonymous function and a closure (even if I use both).

Comment: But +1 for actually knowing the answer. I retract my statement in shame.

Answer (score 3):

Yes , version 2 is called Closure. As far as speed, they are both equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, I read somewhere in Google's pages where it said version 2 (closure) is slower than version 1. I used version 2 all over my code and I don't really want to change it now..

Answer (score 2):

As @Blender said, I also prefer **2**, as it doesn't pollute the global space with (semi-useless) "caller" functions. It's clean, and it simple to understand to someone who knows how `setTimeout` works. And as far as speed goes, there's virtually no difference. [Here's a performance comparison of the two methods](http://jsperf.com/anonymous-vs-named).

However, as far as I understand, it is *not* a closure. It is simply an anonymous function. In JavaScript, as in many other dynamic language, functions are **first class citizens**, meaning that they can be created and passed around- they are objects. However, a closure is more than just an anonymous function. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) explain what a closure is quite succinctly.

Comment: thanks for the link.. excellent description provided there :-)